# Fail to setup multiple bindings to the same destination and group on the consumer side using Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I intend to setup multiple bindings for Kafka Consumer resiliency. More specifically, the backup listener has the same destination and group as the main listener expect the broker IPs. The backup listener's autoStartUp is turned off at startup, but will be turned on programmatic as failover occurs.

However, the micro-service throws the following exception when it launches:

```
org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while starting consumer: 
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:461) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindConsumer(BindingService.java:169) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindConsumer(BindingService.java:126) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindInputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:112) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:58) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'my-kafka-topic-name.my-kafka-consumer-group-name.errors.recoverer' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'my-kafka-topic-name.my-kafka-consumer-group-name.errors.recoverer.errors.recoverer': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:927) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.registerBeanDefinition(GenericApplicationContext.java:323) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.registerBean(GenericApplicationContext.java:471) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.registerErrorInfrastructure(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:681) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.registerErrorInfrastructure(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:633) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:644) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:148) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:407) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Configs:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: mainListener;backupListener;
    stream:
      default-binder: my-main-binder
      function:
        bindings:
          mainListener-in-0: event-in
          backupListener-in-0: backup-event-in
      bindings:
        event-in:                                 <-- main listener
          binder: my-main-binder
          consumer:
            qulifer: local
            use-native-decoding: true
          destination: my-kafka-topic-name
          group: my-kafka-consumer-group-name
        backup-event-in:                          <-- backup listener with autoStartup turned off
          binder: my-backup-binder
          consumer:
            autoStartup: false
            use-native-decoding: true
          destination: my-kafka-topic-name        <-- same destination and group as the main listener
          group: my-kafka-consumer-group-name
      binders:
        my-main-binder:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: ip_1; ip_2;
        my-backup-binder:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: backup_ip_1; backup_ip_2;
```

Dependencies:
spring-cloud-function-context:     3.0.2.RELEASE
spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:  3.0.2.RELEASE

The accepted answer of another post indicates that Qualifier property will be added to address this issue. But I fail to find it in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.ConsumerProperties class in spring-cloud-stream:3.0.2.RELEASE

[Exception thrown while starting consumer - (Cannot assign same group name for different channels in a microservice )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559187/exception-thrown-while-starting-consumer-cannot-assign-same-group-name-for-di)

https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-cloud-stream/commit/5b87b8cae494ae9568d924f64adc436374a67ea7

**Update# 1:**
After the allow-bean-definition-overriding is configured to true as recommended, I saw a different exception as follows:

```
org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while starting consumer: 
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:461) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindConsumer(BindingService.java:169) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindConsumer(BindingService.java:126) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindInputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:112) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:58) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one LastSubscriberMessageHandler is allowed
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderErrorChannel.subscribe(BinderErrorChannel.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.registerErrorInfrastructure(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:712) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.registerErrorInfrastructure(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:633) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:644) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createConsumerEndpoint(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:148) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:407) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

That configuration is not currently supported by default; the error infrastructure bean names are based on the group and destination.

If you don't mind the same error infrastructure being used for both consumers (which sounds ok in this case), you can set

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you for the reply.  I tried your solution, but got another exception saying "Only one LastSubscriberMessageHandler is allowed".  My post is updated with the new logs.

Comment: Sorry; there is no work around then. Perhaps you can describe exactly what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Oh; never mind - I see - different binders. Hmmm - I suggest you open a new feature request against [spring-cloud-stream](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues). Currently, the combination of `group + destination` must be unique.

Comment: Yes, got it - we need some mechanism to customize the error infrastructure bean names instead of using only the group and destination to support this scenario - hence my suggestion to open an issue.

Comment: Cool. I will open a new feature request. Thank you for looking into this issue.

Comment: Hi Gary, any hints how we could achieve resiliency with spring-cloud-stream? When failure is detected, I want the micro-service to programmatically failover to the backup cluster and read from the backup topic on that cluster. We have two clusters configured in active-active architectures. The message offsets of the topic are synced between these them so that they support the Kafka consumer failover.  As the above configs show, I have two difference binders. The only difference the broker IPs. Both the destination and group are the same.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. I am not familiar with active-active clusters but it sounds like you have the bases covered, aside from the issue of duplicated error infrastructure beans.

Comment: BTW, One solution for this use case is to allow the [configuration of an `ABSwitchCluster`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#connecting) for the producer and consumer factories; then you would only need one binder.